# Find the nth item in an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a dataset like so:

```
var data = [{
    "Date": "31/01/2020",
    "Value": 23
  },
  {
    "Date": "29/02/2020",
    "Value": 42
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/03/2020",
    "Value": 52
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/04/2020",
    "Value": 5
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/05/2020",
    "Value": 23
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/06/2020",
    "Value": 15
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/07/2020",
    "Value": 76
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/08/2020",
    "Value": 24
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/09/2020",
    "Value": 34
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/10/2020",
    "Value": 63
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/11/2020",
    "Value": 59
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/12/2020",
    "Value": 48
  }
]
```

I need to access the "Value" property for the First and Last items objects in this array. (eg 23 and 48)

Previously when I just had an array of Values eg [23, 42,  52....] I could use `data[data.length - 12])`  and `data[data.length - 1])` but I'm not sure how to adapt that now for my new data format

Comment: BTW, last element value is `48` not `34`

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the values associated with the earliest and latest date?

Answer (score 1):

It would be the same approach, just adding `.Value` or `.Date`:

```js
var data = [{
    "Date": "31/01/2020",
    "Value": 23
  },
  {
    "Date": "29/02/2020",
    "Value": 42
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/03/2020",
    "Value": 52
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/04/2020",
    "Value": 5
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/05/2020",
    "Value": 23
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/06/2020",
    "Value": 15
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/07/2020",
    "Value": 76
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/08/2020",
    "Value": 24
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/09/2020",
    "Value": 34
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/10/2020",
    "Value": 63
  },
  {
    "Date": "30/11/2020",
    "Value": 59
  },
  {
    "Date": "31/12/2020",
    "Value": 48
  }
];

console.log('First element', data[0].Value, data[0].Date);
console.log('Last element', data[data.length - 1].Value, data[data.length - 1].Date);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the value key of the objects inside the array use the following code:
For value key of 1st array item

```
data[0].Value
```

For last item's value:

```
data[data.length-1].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get first element of an array as `data[0]` and last element as `data[data.length - 1]`

First, you have to get the very first object as `data[0]` and its value is an object

```
{
    Date: "31/01/2020",
    Value: 23,
}
```

and if you want to get the property of an object then you can use `.` or `[]` as

```
obj.Value or obj["value"]
```

```js
var data = [{
    Date: "31/01/2020",
    Value: 23,
  },
  {
    Date: "29/02/2020",
    Value: 42,
  },
  {
    Date: "31/03/2020",
    Value: 52,
  },
  {
    Date: "30/04/2020",
    Value: 5,
  },
  {
    Date: "31/05/2020",
    Value: 23,
  },
  {
    Date: "30/06/2020",
    Value: 15,
  },
  {
    Date: "31/07/2020",
    Value: 76,
  },
  {
    Date: "31/08/2020",
    Value: 24,
  },
  {
    Date: "30/09/2020",
    Value: 34,
  },
  {
    Date: "31/10/2020",
    Value: 63,
  },
  {
    Date: "30/11/2020",
    Value: 59,
  },
  {
    Date: "31/12/2020",
    Value: 48,
  },
];

const first = data[0].Value;
const last = data[data.length - 1].Value;

console.log(first, last);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough. But I assume three cases. Check these three way.

**if you want to see first and last item index then use this -**

```
const first = data.findIndex((d) => d.Value === 23);
const last = data.findIndex((d) => d.Value === 34);
console.log(first, last);
```

**if you want to see access first and last object**

```
const firstObj = data.find((d) => d.Value === 23);
const lastObj = data.find((d) => d.Value === 34);
console.log(firstObj, lastObj);
```

**If you want to see data of that range**

```
var newData = data.slice(first, last + 1);
console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to get the `Value` associated with the earliest and latest date. Ideally you should parse the dates using a library such as [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/), but assuming the format is consistent ("dd/mm/yyyy"), you could just split the date strings like this:

```
const compare = (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0;
const sorter = fn => (a, b) => compare(fn(a), fn(b)); // helper for sorting
data.sort(sorter(d => d.Date.split("/").reverse().join()));  // e.g. "31/01/2020" => "20200131"
```

(Warning: this sorts the data in place.) Then `data[0].Value` and `data[data.length - 1].Value` will give you the first and last.

Alternatively to avoid sorting (e.g. if you have a very long list and don't need to sort the whole thing) you can use a [library like `lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#minBy) to get min and max by date, or write a helper function like this one to loop through:

```
function minAndMaxBy(arr, callBack) {
    let minValue = maxValue = arr[0];
    let minResult = maxResult = callBack(arr[0]);
    for (const value of arr.slice(1)) {
        const result = callBack(value);
        if (result < minResult) {
            minResult = result;
            minValue = value;
        }
        if (result > maxResult) {
            maxResult = result;
            maxValue = value;
        }
    }
    return [minValue, maxValue];
}

const [first, last] = minAndMaxBy(data, d => d.Date.split("/").reverse().join())
console.log(first.Value, last.Value);   // 23, 48
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const {
  [0]: { Value: firstValue },
  [data.length - 1]: { Value: lastValue },
} = data;

console.log(firstValue, lastValue);
```

Comment: Can you add details about how the proposed code addresses the problem? Code-only answers are not very helpful, neither for the asker, nor others.